# Windows compatible games on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: windows, games

Chess Planet (ru) installed through wine on ubuntu 13.04. The desktop shortcut says invalid
encoding.Double click does not open the game.

Answer (score 0):

Desktop shortcuts generally don't work in Wine. You probably need to open your `Home Folder`, then press `Ctrl` + `H` to view hidden files. Then go to `.wine` then `drive_c` then `Program Files` and choose the folder which Chess Planet is in (probably called Convekta) and find a button which looks like it launches the game. Double-click on it and the game should be working as good as it can in normal Wine.

If that doesn't work, you can increase your chances of success by grabbing [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/), redownloading the ChessPlanet and clicking 'Install a program' and then 'Install a non-listed program' and following the instructions. It will then create a working (hopefully) link on the desktop as well as a link in the PlayOnLinux app menu.